# Which one is correct: "number 5 is my favorite number" or "the number five is my favorite number"?

Tags: articles, definite-article

Can you please tell me if I need to use *the* before *number 5* in the following context.

> **Number 5** is my favorite number because it brings me luck.
>
> **The number 5** is my favorite number because it brings me luck.

I've noticed both are used. Are both correct in the context? If no, would you give contexts where you would use one rather than the other?

Comment: Usually numbers one to ten are written as words, not figures, in text that is not a brief note.

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic way of stating it, among us who discuss our favorite numbers or otherwise discuss numbers at parties in this manner, is without either the article or the word "number" - so:

> Five is my favorite number.

"The number five" works here as well but probably wouldn't be as common, if perhaps for no other reason than its wordiness.

"Number five" is marginal; I wouldn't use it. This form is more  of a reference or designation for something:

> "Which lane can we bowl in?"
>
> "[Number] five is available."

Comment: I just don't think when talking about favorite numbers under ten one would use "the".

Answer (score 0):

Both are used and both are acceptable.